# Cypress variable and expecting values

Tags: javascript, cypress

Within Cypress I am opening a JSON file and I want to use values within that file to check in a test.

I open the file using `cy.readfile()` this is my code to read:

```
 let expectedTimeOfTest = "";
  cy.readFile(filePath + fileName).then((json) => {
  expect(json).to.be.an('object')      
  expectedTimeOfTest = JSON.stringify(json.SEQUENCE.timeoftest);
  cy.log(">>" + expectedTimeOfTest);
});
```

When I run the test, I can see in the runner that the text appears in the log as I expect.

Now later on I try to assert, I use:

```
cy.get('.testClass').eq(1).should('have.text', expectedTimeOfTest);
```

However, the test fails with the error "expected .testClass to be '' but got ''

I cannot see what I have done wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: can you log `expectedTimeOfTest` before assert ? what is its value ?
I think since cy.readFile is asynchronous, it might run assert before the `.then` you should move the assert inside `.then`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where you're executing your assertion, and due to Cypress' asynchronous nature, you may be trying to assert before `expectedTimeOfTest` is actually being assigned a value. You have one of two options:

1. Instead of a variable, assign expectedTimeOfTest to an alias: `cy.wrap(JSON.stringify(json.SEQUENCE.timeoftest)).as("expectedTimeOfTest");` which you can then access by its alias as either `this.expectedTimeOfTest` or `cy.get("@expectedTimeOfTest")` later in your test.

If you go this route, do not use the arrow function for your `then` method, as aliases won't work with them. Instead use `.then(function(){ //your code here})`

```
     // Example of using function() vs arrow function.      
     cy.readFile(filePath + fileName).then(function(json){
        expect(json).to.be.an('object')
        cy.wrap(JSON.stringify(json.SEQUENCE.timeoftest)).as("expectedTimeOfTest");
      });
```

2. Include your assertion inside your `.then()` method.

Comment: Aliases don't seem to work. When I try to use them I get undefined

Comment: When are you attempting to access the alias' value? If you are attempting to access the alias before the `.as()` command has run, then you will get an undefined value back. The Cypress documentation around Aliases is pretty comprehensive and can give you an idea of what behavior to expect when using them: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Accessing-Fixtures

Comment: Also, do not use the arrow function for your `then` method, as aliases won't work with them. Instead use `.then(function(){ //your code here})`

Comment: the arrow function was the one I'd seen in all the examples, so if I don't use it, then how to I access the json file?

Comment: @Joseph I've updated the answer to expand on the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `cy.get('.testClass').eq(1).should('have.text', expectedTimeOfTest);` outside of the `.then()` of `cy.readFile()`, then it's better to put it inside because `cy.readFile()` is asynchronous:

```js
cy.readFile(filePath + fileName).then((json) => {
  expect(json).to.be.an('object')      
  expectedTimeOfTest = JSON.stringify(json.SEQUENCE.timeoftest);
  cy.get('.testClass').eq(1).should('have.text', expectedTimeOfTest);
});
```

You can also use aliases:

```js
cy.readFile(filePath + fileName).as('myFile');

cy.get('@myFile')
```